# Python/Json AttributeError: partially initialized module 'json' has no attribute

Tags: python, json

I am running **Windows 10 with MS Code Python 3.7**

I get the following message from my simple code block

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "c:/Users/marke/OneDrive/Desktop/Python Tutorial/json.py", line 1, in
>   module
>       import json   File "c:\Users\marke\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Tutorial\json.py", line 6, in 
>       jsText = json.loads(FileText) AttributeError: partially initialized module 'json' has no attribute 'loads' (most likely due to
>   a circular import)

My code

```
import json

jsFile = open("myjson.json","r")

FileText = jsFile.read
jsText = json.loads(FileText)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you name your script the name of the module you try to import, python tries to imports your script first, which results in the Error

Comment: Exactly . I got the same error -> AttributeError: partially initialized module 'jsondiff' has no attribute 'diff' (most likely due to a circular import).   This solves the issue.